# javascript/jQuery: how do you dynamically turn attribute values into object keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dom, attributes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert form data to JS object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery)

Here is my problem, I have a whole bunch of elements that look like this...

```
<input type="email" id="email" data-item="email" data-key="contact_details"/>
<input type="tel" id="mobileNo" data-item="mobileNo" data-key="contact_details"/>

<input type="text" id="sleeve_length" data-item="sleeve_length" data-key="measurements"/>
<input type="text" id="inseam" data-item="inseam" data-key="measurements"/>
```

Each element has a 'data-key' and 'data-item' which corresponds to the json form i'm trying to turn them into, which will look something like this...

```
{
    "measurements" : {"sleeve_length" : value, "inseam" : value},
```

When each data-item is unique... and like this when it isn't...

```
    "contact_details" : [
                             {"email" : value, "mobileNo" : value},
                             {"email" : value, "mobileNo" : value}
                        ]
}
```

Now because my web app involves many forms, I need a way to dynamically transform the markup above into these json strings... but I can't seem to wrap my head around it!

Does anyone have any idea how I can approach this?

Comment: Do you need one JSON object per group or one for the entire page?

Comment: One for the entire page.

Comment: I can imagine a solution in jQuery... Doing this with just pure JavaScript may be an larger issue here (since you need a selector engine to select those elements)

Comment: I'm happy to use jQuery, my app is chock full of it already!

Comment: @Sime: You only need to select input elements which you can do with `getElementsByTagName` [Works on all browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t12)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery

Comment: @indieinvader My intention is to use an attribute selector instead (so that I can grab all elements with a `data-key` attribute)

Comment: @cybermotron Consider adding the `jQuery` tag to your question then

Comment: @Sime: That's going to be a lot slower than filtering the ones that don't have the attribute (you *are* reading it anyway so you might as well check).

Comment: Have you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery/39248551#39248551

Answer (score 3):

Something like so:

```
var json = {};
$('#path .to input').each(function(e) {
    var key = $(this).attr('data-key');
    var param = $(this).attr('data-item');
    var obj = {};
    obj[param] = $(this).val();

    // If we already have a record...
    if(key in json) {
        // If it's not an array, make it an array
        if(typeof(json[key].push) != 'function')
            json[key] = [ json[key] ];
        // Toss it on the pile
        json[key].push(obj);
    } else {
        // There's only 1 thus far, keep it k/v
        json[key] = obj;
    }
});
```

etc.  Fairly basic, the key points just being testing whether or not the key you're working with exists or not, and if so, converting it to an array.

Edit: this is untested, but it should work.

Edit 2: revised code so your hash key vars don't come across as strings.

Comment: Wow... that certainly takes me closer... the only thing is that it outputs like so {"_id":"contact_1288116316143","firstname":"John","lastname":"Smith","contact_details":[{"param":""},{"param":"sadfsadf"},{"param":"fasdfsad"},{"param":"sadfsad"},{"param":"asdfasdfsadfsa"}],"job_description":[{"param":""},{"param":""}],"fee":[{"param":""},{"param":""}],"measurements":[{"param":""},{"param":""},{"param":""},{"param":""},{"param":""},{"param":""},{"param":""},{"param":""},{"param":""},{"param":""}]}

Comment: Updated the code - sorry about that, short sight on my part. :)  Give it a shot and let me know if that works as expected.

Comment: now it throws up an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (". on this line ...  json[key] = { $(this).attr('data-item'): $(this).val() }; ... although all of the '(' seem to be in the right place.

Comment: My bad - forgot to fix a preliminary edit.  Take a look now.

Comment: That works nearly perfect.  Only problem is that each key/value, becomes its own object, instead of being siblings inside an object.  I just found this amazing plug-in "http://code.google.com/p/form2js/" that does exactly what I want, and gives me some extra wiggle room if I need to  change my data mapping.  Thanks heaps though.  Your answer is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var myJson = {};
// jQuery
$('input').each(function () {
    myJson[$(this).attr('data-key')][$(this).attr('data-value')] = $(this).val();
});
// Native JS
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i += 1) {
    myJson[els[i]['data-key']][els[i]['data-value']] = els[i].value;
}
```

Should do the trick. It loops through all of the input elements on the page and puts the data found in each element into an object with the key `data-key` and sets that equal to an object with the key `data-value` and the value the `value` of the input element.

Helpful?

**Edit:** Is that better? I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: both of these examples come up with errors... the jquery one comes up with "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (" , on the 3rd line of the function... the native js one comes up with "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [" , on the 3rd line of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could let some JS MVC / MVVC library do this for you. For example, [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/). I haven't used it myself yet, but from a glance it seems neat. You define mapping between your JSON object and HTML form fields, and the library would monitor form fields and update the JSON object (a "view model").